# Mock a specific method with http request in Angular for Protractor test scenario

Tags: angular, protractor, httprequest, angular-test

I know this question has been asked many times, but I can't seem to find the right way to mock the backend for this specific situation. I am trying to do some `e2e testing` with `protractor` and for most test scenarios I need to login first. But I don't want to be dependent on the backend so I am looking for a way to mock it. Most of the examples I saw, the method return a promise and they subscribe to it in the `spec` file, but here the subscription is done inside the method.

Here is the type of method I talk about:

```
private logInExistingUser() {
    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('username' , this.username);
    postData.append('password' , this.pwd);

    this.http
      .post('go/login', postData, {withCredentials: true})
      .subscribe(() => this.getProfile());
  }
```

So how can I do the login in my `e2e testing` without being dependent on the backend ?

Any help will be much appreciated.